# Sequelize: include association only IF

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using nodejs v8.9.0 + expressjs v4.14.0 + sequelize v3.25.0 to build a web app in which people can publish articles.

I have these models

```
/** ARTICLE MODEL **/
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Article = sequelize.define('articles', {
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        field: 'title' 
    },
    content: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        field: 'content' 
    }
    anonymous: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        field: 'anonymous' 
    }
},
{
    classMethods: {
        Article .belongsTo(
            models.users, 
            {
                foreignKey: 'userId'
            }
        );
    }
})
```

And

```
/** USER MODEL **/
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var User = sequelize.define('users', {
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        field: 'firstName' 
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        field: 'lastName' 
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        field: 'email'
    },
},
{
    classMethods: {}
})
```

Users can publish articles anonymously or not

Now when I'm querying articles list, I want to include User model only if anonymous is false.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so elegant solution, but work:

```
 Article.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: User,
        required: false,
        where: sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('anonymous'), false)
      }],
    })
```